# Ballerina - Where is Span defined?

Tags: regex, ballerina

I am trying to assign the return value of [regexp:findAll](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.regexp/latest#findAll) to a variable, and I cannot seem to figure it out. The documentation at that previous link says that the return type is `Span[]` but the compiler doesn't seem to know anything about that type. Here is a code fragment:

```
    string:RegExp word_char = re `\w`;
    Span[] spans = word_char.findAll("test string");
```

And I get these errors:

```
| error: unknown type 'Span'
|   Span[] spans = word_char.findAll("test string");
|   ^--^
| error: incompatible types: expected 'other[]', found 'ballerina/lang.regexp:0.0.0:Span[]'
|   Span[] spans = word_char.findAll("test string");
|                  ^------------------------------^
| Compilation aborted due to errors.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Span`](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.regexp/latest#Span) is defined in the same module as the `findAll` function (`lang.regexp`). So it requires importing the `ballerina/lang.regexp` module and using a qualified identifier (with the `regexp` prefix).

```
import ballerina/lang.regexp;

public function main() {
    string:RegExp word_char = re `\w`;
    regexp:Span[] findAll = word_char.findAll("test string");
}
```